# QFileDialog freezes on close/destructor (with selected file or cancel)

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, qt5.4

I'm developing applications in qt with Ubuntu 15.04 and the respective qt pakage 5.4. For some reason, out of nowhere the application would freeze after selecting a file within a `QFileDialog` (or even cancelling).

I found some similar topics on the web but most were concerned with a now resolved bug in qt 5.1 and (non-)native `QFileDialog`s.

Then I found out this is related to more than just my own application - even qtcreator would freeze on leaving the `QFileDialog`, now.

There seems to be a deadlock in the destructor of `QFileDialog`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following snippet is from `qsettings.cpp` (line 1382), within `void QConfFileSettingsPrivate::syncConfFile(int confFileNo)`

```
QLockFile lockFile(confFile->name + QLatin1String(".lock"));
if (!readOnly) {
    if (!confFile->isWritable() || !lockFile.lock() ) {
        setStatus(QSettings::AccessError);
        return;
    }
}
```

It turns out some other qt application has left a lock file which causes all other applications' QFileDialog destructor to be deadlocked within the above `lock` call.

I searched for `.lock` files in my home folder and after deleting 
`./.config/QtProject.conf.lock` and a second file similar to `.config/USERNAME/APPTARGETNAME.conf.lock`
 the QFileDialog works well, agian.

I just now can't reproduce which of the two files did cause the deadlock.

Hope this helps anyone in a similar situation!